# Javascript button Date to Date Nan error

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I am having an issue with a button that converts a Deal Object to an Opportunity Object.

The field I am using from Deal is '{!Deal_Registration__c.Close_Date__c}' which in this format returns 22/10/2014 .

The code I use is :

```
else
{
    alert('{!Deal_Registration__c.Close_Date__c}');

    var dealCloseDate = new Date ('{!Deal_Registration__c.Close_Date__c}');
    alert(dealCloseDate);
    newOpportunity.CloseDate =dealCloseDate;
}
```

When putting this in a date variable I get the alert

> invalid date

and the error:

> {faultcode:'soapenv:Client',
>   faultstring:''NaN-NaN-NaNTNaN:NaN:NaN.NaN-NaN:NaN' is not a valid
>   value for the type xsd:date', }

I have found a way around this by doing a substring and getting the month day year and setting a new date this way.. .but it seems a little overkill.

Does anyone have a suggestion on the proper way of getting this bit of code to work?

P.S. when looking at the field setup they both show as Date and not Datetime..

Comment: what's the output of `alert('{!Deal_Registration__c.Close_Date__c}');` ?

Comment: The output is 22/10/2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to avoid any dependency on date formats. One way to do that is this:

```
var dealCloseDate = new Date({!YEAR(Deal_Registration__c.Close_Date__c)}, {!MONTH(Deal_Registration__c.Close_Date__c)} - 1, {!DAY(Deal_Registration__c.Close_Date__c)});
```

i.e. using the JavaScript date constructor that takes year/month/day. Note that the months are counted from 0 not 1 in JavaScript but from 1 in Salesforce.

Comment: Hi Keith, thanks for the answer, this is the current method that I am using to get the proper date.. it Just seems weird that I would need to do this when I am just copying one date field to another

Comment: @jnoel10 Dates are often awkward because there are so many representations: strings in various formats (that vary per user) that are really meant for end users, milliseconds since 1/1/1970 best for calculations, day/month/year in various orders. And Datetimes are even worse because then timezones are involved too.